# Modifying a library class by having a directory with the same path doesn't work in exported .jar

Tags: java, gradle, jar, classpath

I have a gradle based project where I needed to make a few tweaks to some library classes. I made a package with the same path as the library to override the class. It ends up working fine in my IDE, but when I export it via packr, the application refers to the original library code, not my overridden package code, so I get errors like this.

> class com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: soundCom
> com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.(Lwjgl3Application.java:172)

Sorry if there is terminology I am missing, I'm not too familiar with this process.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution!

Basically you add

```
duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
```

to your dist task in desktop build.gradle